# How to make incompatible, inbuilt printer "act" as a compatible printer?

Tags: android, printing, mobile-development

I recently acquired a Sunmi V2S Plus, POS device. It's a device which runs Android 11, alongside having a 80mm printer inbuilt. The reason in looking to use this device is so that I don't need to have a separate tablet and printer which makes pretty much every single aspect easier.

The problem I am stumbling on is how I get a specific app to recognize this inbuilt printer. The app which I am using is an order taking app from a company called Gloriafood. They have compatibility for the most of Epson and Seiko thermal printers, but not for the device I am using. This includes both network(Ethernet/WiFi) and Bluetooth printers.

The only way I can think of making it work as of now is to somehow make the inbuilt printer "act" as a known compatible printer instead of what its actually is?

The manufacturer of the device does have have a virtual bluetooth connection for the printer, but like earlier, the app can't seem to pick up this one.

I would assume since the manufacturer can make a virtual bluetooth connection for the printer, couldn't I do the save, but just use a driver(or whatever you use) from a compatible printer for the inbuilt one?

Comment: Have you researched the manufacturer site and reviewed their existing developer documentation? https://developer.sunmi.com/docs/en-US/index